# Bootstrap: Responsive tables with WYSIWYG text format

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming

I use WYSIWYG  as text format and inserted tables under the filed using MYSIWYG are not responsive and make the site unresponsive.

It looks really bad in mobile phones.

**Website without table:** [image]

**Website with table:**
[image]

Things I tried so far and didn't work:

1. [Zurb responsive tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_responsive_tables)
2. [Responsive Tables Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables_filter)
3. [Responsive Tables](https://www.drupal.org/node/2188209)
4. After adding table with WYSIWYG I changed the text format to Full HTML and didn't work

Comment: At the end of the day, it's all css. [Responsive Data Tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) - you're welcome.

Comment: @NoSssweat I need a solution to work for all the tables in my site  because different users might add different type of tables

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Use Responsive Tables

To have more control over table columns, use the [Responsive Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables) module. Some details about it (rom its project page):

> Adds a library to allow tables to function better in responsive layouts.
>
> You can manually add the library to any table on the site. You also have the option of using the Better Views Tables module to configure the responsive table controls through the Views UI.

## Option 2: Use a responsive theme

You should consider using a responsive theme, such as (popular) [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega) or [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) themes. There is also the [Beep Edition](https://www.drupal.org/project/beep_edition) "theme", which (quote from project page) "*is designed from the ground up as a mobile-first responsive theme*". However that has like 5 module dependencies ...

For a list of way more (less known) responsive themes, refer to [26 More of the Best Responsive Drupal Themes](https://www.evohosting.co.uk/blog/web-development/drupal-web-development/26-more-best-free-responsive-drupal-themes/). Quote from that link:

> All of these free Drupal themes have responsive layouts, and they include great features like Bootstrap frameworks, Google Fonts, sliders, Font Awesome icons, Facebook integration, social networking icons, and more.

Comment: Vriens, Responsive Tables will not work because different users might add different type of tables, I need a solution to work for all the tables.

Option two: might be great to use the suggested themes, however my website is responsive and it is based on bootstrap which is a responsive theme.